# PrefixAgain solution in codingbat

Tags: java, string

I'm currently doing codingbat problems for fun, and I just done this problem.

"Given a string, consider the prefix string made of the first N chars of the string. Does that prefix string appear somewhere else in the string? Assume
that the string is not empty and that N is in the range 1..str.length(). prefixAgain("abXYabc", 1) → true prefixAgain("abXYabc", 2) → true prefixAgain("abXYabc",
3) → false"
http://codingbat.com/prob/p136417

And my solution is:

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    return (str.replaceFirst(Character.toString(str.charAt(n-1)),"").contains(Character.toString(str.charAt(n-1))));
}
```

Now, I didn't really understand the problem while writing this code and I thought only to find the occurance of the character of the specified index and
ignore the characters before it using the .contains() method. So I'm really not finding the prefix as the problem instructed. I just found my mistake after submitting it. However, this solution passed the exercise.
When I test it with my own input, such as

```
prefixAgain("abcccccbx", 2);
```

it returned true instead of false. So am I missing some reason why codingbat accepted my solution even though it's totally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restate your strategy (algorithm): Do the first N characters in a string appear anywhere else in the string? Simplest solution would be to look for that string in the 2nd through last characters of the original string. Like below (even if someone gives you an assumption, always check!)

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (n < str.length() && 
            (str.substring(1)).indexOf(str.substring(0,n)) > -1
            ) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but my question is why did codingbat accept my wrong solution?

Comment: I am not familiar with codingbat .. but the principles I suggested for this method are ones you should consider using in your programming future. NEVER depend on someone saying you "can assume"! You must always protect your code. If you liked the above answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n)    
    String prefix = str.substring(0, n);
    int length = str.length();

    for (int i = n; i <= length - n; i++) {
        if (prefix.equals(str.substring(i, i + n))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i missed something but this seems correct and elegant:

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    if(str.substring(n).contains(str.substring(0, n))) return true;

    return false;
}
```

If n > str.length() it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  int l= str.length();
  String test = str.substring(0,n);
  boolean flag = false;
  str = str.substring(1);
  l= str.length();
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
    if((i+n <= l)){
      if((str.substring(i,n+i).equals(test)))
      return true;
    }
  }
  return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mine (considering that indexOf() is not introduced yet):

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  for (int i=1; i <= str.length()-n; i++)
    if (str.substring(i, i+n).equals(str.substring(0, n)))
      return true;
  return false;
}
```

But I found this solution the most elegant so far:

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  return (str.indexOf(str.substring(0, n), 1) != -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  return str.substring(n).contains(str.substring(0,n));
}
```

just looking the `prefix(str.substring(0,n))` in the substring of str without the prefix this means starting from n which is (str.substring(n)).

Answer (score 0):

public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {

return (str.substring(n).contains(str.substring(0,n)));
}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This has been posted basically, but I revised it a little to make it super easy to read instead of going for the one liner.

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  String prefix = str.substring(0, n);
  String afterPrefix = str.substring(n);
  return afterPrefix.contains(prefix);
}
```

First, we grab the prefix which will start at index zero and go up to not including n. afterPrefix is simply the rest of the string which will start at n. Finally, return whether everything after the prefix contains the prefix.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
    String pre = str.substring(0, n);

    for (int i=n; i<str.length()-n+1; i++)
    {
        if (str.substring(i, i+n).equals(pre))
           return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: more costly coding that making use of existing methods.

Answer (score -1):

A solution, not the fastest but clear.

```
public boolean prefixAgain(String str, int n) {
  String prefix = str.substring(0,n); // prefix String
  int index = str.indexOf(prefix); //first loc of prefix
  if(str.lastIndexOf(prefix) > index){ //see if it appears again
  return true; 
  }
  else return false; //if we get here, doesn't appear again, false
}
```

Comment: The question assumes it's a *prefix*, i.e., the first N characters, so there's no reason to search for its first incidence, which will always start at the 0th character.

Comment: I know, I just did to "show" my work as my CS teacher used to say.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Pardon me if im wrong but I believe that there is reasoning behind getting the prefix String, calling substring twice for indexOf and lastIndexOf is wasteful and there is no point, why call substring(0, n) once for indexOf and again for lastIndexOf.